# PagedDataSource and UpdatePanel don't work together

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, datalist

I have a problem with PagedDataSource and UpdatePanel.When I use AsyncPostBackTrigger in my buttons, paging in my page disappear.

Here's asp code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
           <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:DataList ID="DataListGallery" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnItemDataBound="DataListGallery_ItemDataBound"   >
                   <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:HiddenField ID="FieldPhoneId" Value='<%# Eval("Phone_InfoID") %>' runat="server" />
                       <asp:ImageButton ID="btnShop" OnClick="btnShop_Click" ImageUrl="images/cart.gif" CssClass="left_bt_item" title="header=[خريد] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]" runat="server" />
                       <asp:ImageButton CssClass="left_bt_item" title="header=[مورد علاقه] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]" OnClick="btnFavourite_Click" ID="btnFavourite"  ImageUrl="images/unfav.png" runat="server" />
                                               .
                                               .
                                               .
```

Here's C# code(load event):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/how-to-determine-whether-an-asynchronous-partial-postback-has-occurred-on-page.aspx

    // get a reference to ScriptManager and check if we have a partial postback

    if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).IsInAsyncPostBack)
    {

        // partial (asynchronous) postback occured

        // insert Ajax custom logic here  

    }
    // enable property is re-creating page controls
    else if (!Page.IsPostBack || enable)
    {
        //enable = false;
        if (Page.Request["Page"] != null || Page.Request["Page"] != "")
        {
        .
        .
        .
```

And a button with AsyncPostBackTrigger:

```
protected void btnFavourite_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    // Access to real ImageButton from repeater
    ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)sender;

    HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)ib.Parent.FindControl("FieldPhoneId");

    Favourite objFav = new Favourite(Convert.ToInt32(hf.Value));

    Guid userId = objFav.GetUserIdFromUserName(User.Identity.Name);

    using (var context = new MobileGalleryEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            // Delete favorited
            if (objFav.HadFavorited(User.Identity.Name))
            {
                int phoneInfoId = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToInt32(hf.Value));

                // Remove favourite
                objFav.RemoveFromFavourite(userId);

                // Change image
                ib.ImageUrl = "~/images/unfav.png";
            }
            // Add favorite
            else
            {
                // Add phone
                objFav.AddToFavourite(userId);

                // Change image
                ib.ImageUrl = "~/images/favs.gif";
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Here's DataBound event:

```
protected void DataListGallery_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        try
        {                
            // Get LoginView for access to ImageButton on it.
            var loginView = e.Item.FindControl("LoginView1");

            ImageButton btnCom = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnCompare");
            //ImageButton btnFav = (ImageButton)loginView.FindControl("btnFavourite");
            ImageButton btnFav = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnFavourite");
            btnFav.Visible = true;

            ImageButton btnShop = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnShop");
            btnShop.Visible = true;

            //HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)loginView.FindControl("FieldPhoneId");
            HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("FieldPhoneId");

            List<int> listFav = (List<int>)Session["Fav"];

            if (listFav.Contains(int.Parse(hf.Value)))
                btnFav.ImageUrl = "~/images/favs.gif";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        ImageButton btnFav = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnFavourite");
        btnFav.Visible = false;
        ImageButton btnShop = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnShop");
        btnShop.Visible = false;

    }
}
```

When I fire btnFavourite button, paging in my page disapear. but when i use FullPostBack it's work.
Notice that when I use FullPostBack, I re-create controls such as paging control and other control but when I use AsyncPostBackTrigger I didn't re-create controls.

What am I doing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have to re-create controls again the same as FullPostBack.